# Can't use 'If-None-Match' request header with Facebook android SDK

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I'm using Facebook android SDK to execute a graph call to fetch all my friends. I'm trying to use the 'If-None-Match' request header but I can't find a way to add headers to the request. I'm managing to get the eTag header from the response but without an option to use it. Here is my code:

```
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("fields", "id,installed,name,picture");

    new com.facebook.Request(
            ParseFacebookUtils.getSession(),
            "/me/friends",
            bundle,
            HttpMethod.GET,
            new Request.Callback() {
                /**
                 *
                 * @param response
                 */
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(com.facebook.Response response) {

                    // Getting the eTag using response.getHttpConnection.getHeader("eTag");

                }
            }
    ).executeAsync();
```

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm having the same issue now

Comment: No I didn't. But i haven't tried too much because Facebook change the list of /me/friends to return only friends that are using the app.

Comment: Just so you know I had to use a custom HttpUrlConnection instead and handle it that way. I don't think you can access the request's headers otherwise.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about it too

Comment: This should be added man...